# SMTP module: The following From address failed

Tags: 7, emails

all,

Here is something I don't quite understand.

First of all, my site-wide email address configured on Site Information page is **my_gmail_address@gmail.com**.

Then, I use [smtp](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module to send emails out from my site. I configure SMTP settings with my yahoo email address **my_yahoo_mail_address@ymail.com**.

I tries to send a test email out to my other gmail address **my_other_gmail_address@gmail.com**, but failed. Email can never be sent out in this situation.

Here is watchdog log details:

```
Type    smtp
Date    Monday, September 22, 2014 - 11:29
User    lyon
Location    http://localhost:8888/drupal-test/admin/config/system/smtp
Referrer    http://localhost:8888/drupal-test/admin/config/system/smtp
Message Error sending e-mail from my_gmail_address@gmail.com to my_other_gmail_address@gmail.com : The following From address failed: my_gmail_address@gmail.com
SMTP server error: From address not verified - see http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/original/manage/sendfrom-07.html

Severity    error
Hostname    ::1
Operations
```

SMTP configuration didn't go wrong, because in the following two situations, email can be sent out well:

1. configure site-wide email address to be the same one configured in SMTP settings: **my_yahoo_mail_address@ymail.com**.
2. configure SMTP settings with a gmail address, then configuring site-wide email address to be any email address will work well. (People on Internet says Gmail can override it).

I don't want the SMTP configuration to be tied with Gmail account, it should support any mail host. How can I overcome this problem?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do you use Yahoo to send Gmail emails in the first place?  Any particular reason to do that?

Comment: I didn't use Yahoo to send Gmail emails. I configured SMTP with my Yahoo account, and was trying to send an email to my Gmail account.

Comment: But your "from" address is \@gmail.com not \@ymail.com, so only gmail's SMTP can be expected to send it without problems. In old days with no mail security (199x) you could use any SMTP to send mails with any "from". That is no longer true, people kinda didn't like it when someone was impersonating their clients, and now without SMTP admin's cooperation you cannot do that, you must use SMTP of company that is hosting your "from" address.

Comment: OK, thank you for this great tips. My question now is that if it is possible to overwrite drupal site-wide email address to be @ymail.com in code programmatically?

Comment: or do I have to configure site-wide email address to match smtp_username I put in SMTP configuration page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem lies with Yahoo not having your permission to send from the gmail account.  You could try setting up Yahoo to send from your gmail account but I'm not sure Yahoo will do that.

You could look into a mail service like [MailJet](http://www.mailjet.com), which is cheap and scalable.

Or, assuming you're using the [drupal_mail](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7) function, simply set your $from variable in 'params' to 'my_yahoo_mail_address@ymail.com'.

Comment: thanks for answering my question. MailJet sounds good. But is there any way I could simply override the mail from address to be SMTP from address rather than using site-wide mail address programmatically?

Comment: Oh yes, the other option I forgot to write in... does that help?

Comment: Yes I am using `drupal_mail` function. And no, setting `$from` variable to 'my_yahoo_mail_address@ymail.com' didn't work out. I even set `$from` to be smtp_username variable I configured in smtp module, but still, when I `dpm` the $from variable in `smtp.mail.inc` file under smtp module, it keep showing the site-wide email address..

Comment: Ok.. Now I got it. You second option works on my own custom module. It was a problem in the test mail function of smtp module. `$from` is omitted in its `drupal_mail` function. see line #149 under smtp.admin.inc in smtp module. I will accept your answer, thanks for your time.

Comment: Ah right, good sleuthing and you're welcome =)